# compare two array value and remove the duplicate value and store another array lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

how to compare two array value and remove the duplicate value and store another array using lodash for example

```
var array1=['1', '2', '3', '4']
var array2=['5', '1', '8', '10', 3]

var result = ['2','4','5','8','10']
```

Comment: btw, `'3'` !== `3`!

Comment: @klugjo i am not expecting to u write code, I asking the possible thing

Comment: Create a common accumulator, iterate through the first array and record the frequency and then iterate through other array and decrement the previous value frequency and add new numbers. Later on, filter on this accumulator on value whose frequency count is not zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just concat the arrays and check the indices from left and right side. If equal, take the unique value.

This solution takes only `'3'` for both arrays.

```js
var array1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
    array2 = ['5', '1', '8', '10', '3'],
    result = array1.concat(array2).filter((v, _, a) => a.indexOf(v) === a.lastIndexOf(v));

console.log(result);
```

With lodash's [`_.xor`](https://lodash.com/docs/#uniq)

> Creates an array of unique values that is the [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) of the given arrays. The order of result values is determined by the order they occur in the arrays.

```js
var array1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
    array2 = ['5', '1', '8', '10', '3'],
    result = _.xor(array1, array2);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great but If there is a duplicate in array1 or array2, it will not work.