# Diff 2 strings in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

Let's say I have the following 2 strings that were returned from `JSON.stringify`:

```
list1 = ["mike","bob", "jim", "steve", "ed"]
list2 = ["bob", "jim", "steve"]
```

and I want to do something like this:

```
Diff(list1, list2)
```

and return this:

```
mike, ed
```

because mike and ed are what's different between the lists. Does anyone have something laying around that will do this simply and accurately? I'd like to avoid recreating the wheel if possible.

Comment: And you didn't tried anything? (also, you have 2 *arrays* of strings, `list1` and `list2`)

Comment: something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/48221473/1447675

Comment: Also potentially useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58626502/how-could-i-improve-and-shorten-the-following-algorithm-which-compares-two-array

Comment: ```const diff = [...list1.filter(elem => !list2.includes(elem)), ...list2.filter(elem => !list1.includes(elem))];```